# why use a logical operator in javascript function declaration

Tags: javascript

I'm looking at some JavaScript code and I can't figure out why a logical operator (!) is being used in function declaration.  This is a tiny extract:

```
   ! function (a) {

        ! function (a)
        {
            "use strict";
            a.Shorthand = {
                UI: {},
                helpers: {},
                Data: {}
            }
        }(window),  ...
}(!1);
```

I'm pretty sure its an IIFE (when complete) and it's main purpose is minification but that's as far as I go. I've not come across any explanation.
When the rest of the code is there it all works.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's about function expression needed instead of function declaration for IIFE. If function is used as expression it can be invoked imidiatelly. If it's not a part of an expression it can't so this code won't work:

```
function(){}()
```

while this will work:

```
!function(){}()
(function(){}())
(function(){})()
var a = function(){}()
```